# string in list: Incorrectly returning false (request.args)

Tags: python, spotify

I'm stumped at this:

```py
@bp.route('/api/spotify_auth')
def api_spotify_auth():
    code = request.args.get("code", None)
    error = request.args.get("error", None)
    state = request.args.get("state").strip("\"'")

    if state not in Spotify.valid_states:
        return jsonify({
            "error": "State returned was not valid",
            "states": Spotify.valid_states,
            "state": state,
            "check": state in Spotify.valid_states
        }), 500
```

I'm expecting the call to include a `state` parameter which has previously been added to the list, `Spotify.valid_states`. However, when requesting the route I get:

```
{
  "check": false, 
  "error": "State returned was not valid", 
  "state": "07fec2ea-123f-42e8-9e64-07026ca87ae5", 
  "states": [
    "07fec2ea-123f-42e8-9e64-07026ca87ae5"
  ]
}
```

Evidently, python returns `false` to `state in states`... but to me it looks like this should return `true`.

Someone mentioned the quotes causing issues hence the `.strip("\"'")`, however the issue persists.

Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: `Spotify.valid_states` looks to contain uuids, are you sure it is a list of strings and not uuids?

Comment: `Spotify.valid_states` might be a list of objects whose `repr` just looks like a 'normal' Python string, but since `in` uses equality it will fail when used against an `str` object. You should make sure what `Spotify.valid_states` really contains (try `print(type(Spotify.valid_states[0]))`)

Comment: Wow you're both spot on - I had considered something funny with the uuid but it's acted just like a string in my testing so I hadn't realised it was anything but. Converting to a string immediately when I create the uuid fixed it. Much appreciated :)